# How to use JOIN in mysql to show all data which are not matching

Tags: mysql, join

I want to show data from 2 tables and I want to show them all including data that are not matching. I've tried with this query.

```
SELECT * FROM student s
LEFT JOIN grade g ON g.student_id=s.student_id
WHERE s.student_id = 9
```

What I get is only showing students who have grade while what I need is showing all students even if they don't have any grade. I also tried using `inner join`, `right join` but the result is just the same. What should the query be?

Comment: add sample data table ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is `WHERE s.student_id = 9`, because un matching rows from the left table (students table), will have `s.student_id` equal null, and this where clause will remove these rows with nullable `student_id` values because null is not equal to 9 or even anything.

Try to move the `where` to the `join` condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN grade g ON g.student_id=s.student_id AND s.student_id = 9;
```

Or use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student s
WHERE s.student_id = 9
  AND student_id NOT IN(SELECT student_id 
                        from grade 
                        where student_id is not null);
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you say I think you misunderstood how SQL JOIN clause works.
If that's not the case then we will need more informations about what's inside theese tables and what you need to display.

Your query is :

> SELECT * FROM student s
>
> LEFT JOIN grade g ON g.student_id=s.student_id
>
> WHERE s.student_id = 9

What you need is :

> what I need is showing all students even if they don't have any grade

What is your query asking for :

*"Select all the data regarding students having their ID equal to 9 in both Students and Grade tables"*

The first quastion to ask there is : Do you realy need data from the Grade table ?

If yes then your WHERE clause is the problem and you may not want to get only students with ID=9 but also others (then check out @Brittain Ze 's answer with the **NOT IN** clause)

If not (and what you need is what you said) then `SELECT * FROM Student WHERE student_id = 9` should do the job.
You will get informations about all the students, without informations about their grades.